# Is it an anti-pattern to exit useEffect hook early?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In other words, add a conditional judgment to the `useEffect` hook to determine whether the execution of the effect is an anti-pattern.

Consider the following code:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function useCustomEffect(dep) {

  const condition = complexCaculate(dep);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!condition) return; // exit early
    // fetch API work. 
  }, [dep]);
}

function complexCaculate(dep) {
  // some complex caculation
}
```

I think if the condition is false, the callback of `useEffect` should not be executed.

Comment: This is not an antipattern at all.  Its very common to wrap everything inside a useEffect inside an `if` block to make sure that you want to actually produce an effect, based on some condition of a new dependency value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not an anti-pattern, but based on the existing code there's a slight improvement possible:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function useCustomEffect(dep) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const condition = complexCaculate(dep);

    if(!condition) return; // exit early
    // fetch API work. 
  }, [dep]);
}

function complexCaculate(dep) {
  // some complex caculation
}
```

With this modification, `complexCalculate()` is only called whenever the effect is called, rather than every time the component in which `useCustomEffect()` is called is re-rendered.